# Credit Rolls.. How do I get the credit rolls to look good? FCPX and Motion5

Tags: editing, post-production

I use Motion 5 to create credit roll export. 
It just looks awesome. THEN, I import it into FCPX and after export, it looks jumpy.

Does anyone have the golden tip? I've heard about Motion Blur.. tried it.. didn't do the job. I'm beginning to think that I have to export the file without credits and import into Motion 5 to attach the credits and export again.. 
(Haven't tried that, but a .mov from motion works)

Appreciate the input.

Comment: Is your final output interlaced? There's some special voodoo you need to make credit rolls work when interlaced: you need to move a multiple of two pixels vertically with each frame.

Answer (score 1):

> it looks jumpy

Most probably you have mismatch of framerates between Motion 5 project and FCPX. Check if they match. Also check all other video settings, to match your FCPX composition.

Comment: Add motion blur if your finished titles are moving more than 3px per frame.

Comment: Hi Shultc,

You are so right.. I did have Motion set to 59fps. Then it looks awesome. 
The project was in 24fps..so that makes it bad. 

However, I tried the credit roll in 24fps in Motion and then it looks bad too. 
The motion blur helps a little, but not a lot. 

I did notice it in the cinema sometimes as well, that it is jumpy when on 24fps. Is there a way to do it properly on 24fps without the jumpy/jittery scroll? Do you know?

Comment: It is difficult to say, without looking. If you are talking about thing, that you see how frames are changed on 24fps, then no. You can only make more frames, for more flued scroll. Or make scroll slower. I did not worked with both of your programs, but you can try to change framerate to 48fps (24fps*2). Maybe it will help.